# Edit and continue does not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012

i am trying to edit my code in visual studio 2012 by that time it is deleting the next character 
For example I declared one statement ---- con=new sqlconnection();------
after some time i want to change the object name "con" as "scon" ,when i press the character "s" ,the character "c" automatically is going to be disappeared then "o", then "n" like this.
Even if want to change a single character but it is allowing me to write all the code up to the ending
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might have the **Insert mode** activated. Check at the bottom right of the Visual Studio window whether there is  **INS** symbol which shows that Insert mode is activated as outlined in red in the image below. To disable press the  <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on your keyboard.

[image: Insert Mode activated in Visual Studio]